# How does #(for [x %, i (range %2)] x) do what it does?

Tags: clojure

I'm working through the `4clojure.com` problems (this is from problem 33), and I can't for the life of me figure out how this works:

```
(#(for [x %, i (range %2)] x) [1 2 3] 2)   ; --> '(1 1 2 2 3 3)
```

I can see that `for` binds `x` to `[1 2 3]` and then does *something* twice (`i` is bound to `'(0 1)`), but I'd expect an answer like `'([1 2 3] [1 2 3])`. It looks like this code is somehow doing a `mapcat` on the output.

The docstring for `for` includes the following: `Collections are iterated in a nested fashion, rightmost fastest...`. This gives me the intuition that `i` is taking on the values `0, 1, 2` for `x`, but I can't say I understand what's going on.

Can somebody explain what's going on in a way that improves my mental model of how `for` works? Many thanks!

Comment: each element in `x` is "used" as many times as there are elements in `i`. For example: `(for [x [1 2 3] i [0 0]] x)` will give you the same result `(1 1 2 2 3 3)`

Comment: tolitius and Jared314, thanks for both your answers. Jared314, my thinking was flawed about what `x` binds to. Your answer--very well written!--helped me understand a different use of `for` that had also baffled me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you fill in the function arguments you get the following:

```
(for [x [1 2 3]
      i (range 2)]
  x)
;; => (1 1 2 2 3 3)
```

Where:

```
(range 2) ;; => (0 1)
```

The rightmost item the docstring is referring to is `i`, which has two elements. So, if you unroll the loop, `x` and `i` would progress like the following table:

```
(clojure.pprint/print-table
  (for [x [1 2 3] i (range 2)] {:x x :i i}))

| :x | :i |
|----+----|
|  1 |  0 |
|  1 |  1 |
|  2 |  0 |
|  2 |  1 |
|  3 |  0 |
|  3 |  1 |
```

The result of `for` is a list containing the results returned for every iteration of the loop. In this case you are just returning `x`, so your resulting list would correspond to only the `x` column in the above table.